# Magento extension menu

Tags: php, magento

How can I move my extension link (standard study NEWS extension) from main menu to "Promotions" menu?

Magentostudy -> NEWS extension have the:

```
<config>
<menu>
     <news translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
        <title>News</title>
        <sort_order>65</sort_order>
        <children>
            <manage translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                <title>Manage News</title>
                <action>adminhtml/news</action>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            </manage>
        </children>
     </news>
</menu>

<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <news translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                    <title>News</title>
                    <sort_order>65</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <manage translate="title">
                            <title>Manage News</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <save translate="title">
                                    <title>Save News</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </save>
                                <delete translate="title">
                                    <title>Delete News</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </delete>
                            </children>
                        </manage>
                    </children>
                </news>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <news translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                                    <title>News Management</title>
                                </news>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

I know that code this code provide some logic to make admin menu link to my extension visible, bu HOW can I move it to "Promotions" menu!

I know that is simple task, but Magento team write "perfect" documentation, so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your menu section xml code with below code:

```
<menu>
 <promo translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">        
    <sort_order>65</sort_order>
    <children>
        <manage translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
            <title>Manage News</title>
            <action>adminhtml/news</action>
            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
        </manage>
    </children>
 </promo>
</menu>
```

It will add `Manage News` link under `Promotions`.

Hope will help!

Comment: but how? How it's work? I cant find "Promotions" in this code!

Comment: @LubomurMarshal, Magento use `<promo>` for "Promotions" module. If this works, can you also mark this as useful.

Comment: my reputation is 10, 15 requires!